# CMake Presets setting source folder / build folder / other specific arguments

Tags: cmake, cmake-presets

Is it possible to use cmake-presets to specify the build folder/source folder, other arguments other than the architecture or Release/Debug?

Example:

```
{
    "version": 3,
    "cmakeMinimumRequired": {
      "major": 3,
      "minor": 27,
      "patch": 0
    },
    "configurePresets": [
      {
        "name": "Release",
        "description": "Release configuration",
        "hidden": false,
        "cacheVariables": {
          "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Release"
        },
        "architecture":"x64"
        # This would not work
        "buildDirectory": "build/release"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: There is `binaryDir`  parameter: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html#configure-preset.

Comment: I missed that, thanks!